# Pass a read-only variable to a CHANGING parameter

Tags: abap

I'd like to display a table from a class instance using CL_SALV_TABLE. However, my table is read-only and it's to be passed to a CHANGING parameter, I'm not allowed to do so.

How can I copy my dynamic reference to something that I can pass? The data type of the attribute can by any table.

> Call of method FACTORY of the class CL_SALV_TABLE has failed; the
>   actual parameter for T_TABLE is write-protected.

```
DATA(lv_attribute) = 'mt_attribute'. "Dynamic name of class attribute        
ASSIGN lr_appclass->(lv_attribute) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lt_table>).

cl_salv_table=>factory( 
          IMPORTING r_salv_table = DATA(lr_salv_table) 
          CHANGING  t_table      = <lt_table> ).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without runtime typing:

```
ASSIGN lr_appclass->('MT_ATTRIBUTE') TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<member>).
DATA(copied_member) = copy( <member> ).
ASSIGN copied_member->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<table>).

cl_salv_table=>factory(
  IMPORTING
    r_salv_table = DATA(lr_salv_table)
  CHANGING
    t_table      = <table> ).
```

with

```
METHODS copy
  IMPORTING
    data          TYPE any
  RETURNING
    VALUE(result) TYPE REF TO data.

METHOD copy.
  CREATE DATA result LIKE data.
  ASSIGN result->* TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<result>).
  <result> = data.
ENDMETHOD.
```

I added the method `copy` to clarify what's happening. Its code can also be added to the main function.

Comment: This one fails with "Dynamic attribute declarations are not supported in the current statement".

Comment: You're right, I forgot that. I gave the answer a workover and tested the code.

Comment: To make COPY a reusable method, I would take ASSIGN outside the method so that you can copy anything, and the signature would become `copy importing DATA_OBJECT TYPE ANY returning value(result) type ref to data` + some adequate changes inside the method.

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [RTTS](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=42965) to generate dynamic variables.

To generate a dynamic internal table with same type of original:

```
DATA: lo_table_desc TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr, " RTTS table descriptor
      lrt_copy      TYPE REF TO DATA.               " temp data ref
FIELD-SYMBOLS:
               <lt_copy> TYPE ANY TABLE.

" original type determination
lo_table_desc ?= cl_abap_tabledescr=>describe_by_data( {HERE_GOES_THE_MEMBER_TABLE} ).

" dynamic allocation
CREATE DATA lrt_copy TYPE HANDLE lo_table_desc.
ASSIGN lrt_copy->* TO <lt_copy>.

" {NOW_USE_<lt_copy>}
```

Comment: Preferrably <lt_copy> TYPE ANY **TABLE** so that to make it possible statements like LOOP AT <lt_copy>. Note also that the code will work for standard, sorted and hashed tables, but all ALV APIs need a **standard** table.

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi for your enlightening comment. Edited.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Small edit: It's "cl_abap_tabledescr" with an "r".

Comment: Thanks @MikaelG. Fixed.